# Meteor settings for accounts-facebook-cordova not configured correctly

Tags: meteor, cordova-plugins

I am seeing facebook cordova settings issue after upgrading the Meteor framework from 1.0.2 to 1.0.4 version. Please let me know if anyone has seen this issue before?

**meteor run ios** 
"Meteor settings for accounts-facebook-cordova not configured correctly"

Comment: Try the instructions in this [link](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-1-0-4-facebook-plugin-fails-to-load-on-mobile-platforms/1921/3)